# "PublicKeyToken <..> is not a valid extension type." Error?

Tags: .net, sql, vb.net, visual-studio

I added an UPDATE statement to my application which works fine. It updates the database correctly and other than the four error messages, I am seeing no problems. What does this mean?

```
Error   1   Type Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Sql90DatabaseSchemaProvider, Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql, Version=10.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a is not a valid extension type.        0   0   
Error   2   Type Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Sql100DatabaseSchemaProvider, Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql, Version=10.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a is not a valid extension type.       0   0        
Error   3   Type Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Sql110DatabaseSchemaProvider, Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql, Version=10.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a is not a valid extension type.       0   0   
Error   4   Type Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SqlAzureDatabaseSchemaProvider, Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql, Version=10.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a is not a valid extension type.     0   0
```

My code:

```vb
Using sqlCon = New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ITCSDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
    sqlCon.Open()
    Dim name As String = "Name"
    Dim link As String = "link"
    Dim dec As Integer = 0
    Dim sqlUpdate = "INSERT INTO appTable " & _
    "VALUES (41, @name, @link, 0, @dec, 0)"
    Dim updateCmd = New SqlCommand(sqlUpdate, sqlCon)
    updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", Name)
    updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@link", link)
    updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dec", dec)
    updateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    sqlCon.Close()
End Using
```

*Note: it is a Local Database (.mdf) stored locally on the user's machine.
**The local variables; name, link and dec are just for testing. Once it works correctly, they will be replaced by user input.

Comment: Can someone also edit my title to what is approved by this website?

Comment: Exactly what is showing you those error messages?  Where do you see them and when?

Comment: The "Error List" built into Visual Studios 2012. It compiles and runs fine. *Sorry if that is not the correct terminology for the error list.

Comment: Phil,  hope you see how the edited title is a better title. In fact, I knew this question was yours just by seeing the title that contained almost no information.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Not that again ;)

Comment: also, what versions of Visual Studio and .Net?  (Sorry for all of the follow-ups, but this is info you want to include in your questions for the best responses.)

Comment: I just edited about five of his titles. This is just how he creates titles, and I do wish it would stop.

Comment: And I immediately asked if someone could please edit the title. I am learning sir. 
@rynah - Hey :)

Comment: @RBarryYoung - during "debugging". I think that is correct. Right after I press start to test the application.

Comment: I am working on it John. I understand now that it is not acceptable. Thank you.

Comment: @PhilJFry: I was hoping that if you looked at the edited title and compared it to your own, that you'd learn to create better titles.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - Visual Studios 2012 Ultimate

Comment: so what does it mean @JohnSaunders? Everything works fine. Why am I seeing this ?

Comment: @PhilJFry Neither John Saunders (I assume) nor I knew the answer, but with a good title, the right tags and the right information, someone who *did* know the answer noticed it and came here to post it.  For a good title think of this: "*If I had to state my question in only 5 to 12 words, how could I do that and still have a chance of getting the right answer?*" Remembering that you do not need to include things that can be tags to the title, because if they are tags only, they can still be seen and filtered on in the Questions lists that Answerers use to find questions that they can answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems to be a [known problem](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/728838/visual-studio-11-shows-errors-even-it-built-succeeded) of VisualStudio 2012. Restarting should help to remove these messages.

Comment: Thank you. Restart took care of the issue and to add it was not related to the code listed above. The public key the error was making reference to was in my app.config file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Using sqlCon = New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ITCSDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
    sqlCon.Open()
    Dim name As String = "Name"
    Dim link As String = "link"
    Dim dec As Integer = 0
    Dim sqlUpdate = "INSERT INTO appTable " & _
    "VALUES (41, @name, @link, 0, @dec, 0)"
    Dim updateCmd = New SqlCommand(sqlUpdate, sqlCon)
    updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", Name)
    updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@link", link)
    updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dec", dec)
    updateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    sqlCon.Close()
End Using
```